# x-axis not aligned in adjacent plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to align the x-axis of these two plots unsuccessfully. Makes me wonder what's wrong?

```
 \documentclass{article}  
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,width=7cm}

 \begin{document}  

 \begin{tikzpicture} 
 \begin{axis}[  
    xlabel={$t$},  
    ylabel={$f(t)$},  
    axis lines=center,  
    xmin=0,xmax=5,  
    ymin=0,ymax=1.5,  
    ytick={0.368,1},  
    xtick={1},  
    xticklabels={$\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$},  
    yticklabels={$\dfrac{\lambda}{e}$,$\lambda$}  
]
\addplot +[mark=none,smooth] {e^(-x)};  
\draw [dashed] (0,0.368) -| (1,0);  
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\hspace{2cm}  
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}[  
    xlabel={$t$},  
    ylabel={$\lambda(t)$},  
    axis lines=center,  
    xmin=0,xmax=5,  
    ymin=0,ymax=1.5,  
    ytick={1},  
    xtick={},  
    xticklabels={},  
    yticklabels={$\lambda$}  
]  
\addplot +[mark=none,smooth] {1};  
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

I added `[baseline]` to both `\begin{tikzpicture}` so that it now looks `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]`. It fixed the problem.